# Redirecting the URL requests?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have one flash file which is embading in another, the embeded one is creating a requests over HTTP to a specific host, I wish to redirect thoose requests to another host without touching the source code of the embeded one.

- is it possible, and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible on the server-side using PHP or ColdFusion or whatever floats your boat, but at the client, nope...

Comment: I see :| Thank you very much for the fast response :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible with Flash (not even with AIR.) The best you could do is take URLs into external config/flashvars and change them here.